# 3D array using data from existing lists

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I am new to python and am having trouble with multi-dimensional arrays. I have a list(s) of points in 3-dimensions(x,y,z) that I am trying to use in marching_cubes_lewiner(). The co-ordinate values are in 3 lists: x,y and z such that any point will be given by (x[i],y[i],z[i]).

Now, marching_cubes_lewiner() accepts volume as a 3D numpy array. What would be the best way to convert the 3 lists into a 3D numpy array?

I have tried:

```
s=len(x)
points = np.ndarray((s,s,s),buffer=np.array([x,y,z]), dtype=float)
```

but am getting the following error: buffer is too small for requested array. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Edit: 
I apologize for the question not not being very clear.
The co-ordinates of all points are in this [text file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JTqD6TN8tKG9TslQ1FMpl-6GnWnvw5xM/view?usp=sharing) in the format "x y z".

Reg. the output: I would like to get a 3D numpy array that would be compatible with(be the input of) the marching cubes function provided [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.marching_cubes_lewiner). To clarify, the output would be the 'volume' of the function above. I apologize again for the  wording of this problem not being coherent.

Here is the error I am currently getting:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-3be08f942830> in <module>
      9 
     10 s=len(x)
---> 11 t = np.ndarray((s,s,s),buffer=np.array([x,y,z]), dtype=float)

TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array
```

Comment: How are you reading the coordinates?

Comment: The coordinates are generated and stored in my program as a dictionary.
I use the following code to split them up into lists:
x=[]
y=[]
z=[]
for planes in contours:
    for points in planes:
        x.append(points['x'])
        y.append(points['y'])
        z.append(points['z'])

Comment: I'm trying a few things, do you have an example of what the output should look like?

Comment: @AMC: Thank you for trying. 
Unfortunately, I am new to python and this is the first time I am using the marching cubes algorithm. I am trying to follow the example given here: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_marching_cubes.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-edges-plot-marching-cubes-py 

I wanted to test by feeding my geometry in place of the ellipsoid.

Comment: I saw that page, it isn't evident to me what the shape of the data should be.