# Input format for marching_cubes_lewiner()?

Tags: python, scikit-image, marching-cubes

This is the first time I am using the marching cubes algorithm and am wondering what would be the right format for volume input for the marching_cubes_lewnier() function?

I am following this [example](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_marching_cubes.html) and would like to use my set of [points](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ApyKbzkgjKk11x-RDW8kHsPEp7m_ZOMb/view?usp=sharing) in place of ellipse_double in the example.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the documentation for the function not help? https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#marching-cubes-lewiner

Comment: @AKX : I looked at it but am unable to find the right format to feed into volume. I have asked about it earlier(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60310925/3d-array-using-data-from-existing-lists) as well but with no success. If you could provide some insight, it'd be great.
Thanks!